# Install django-app without PIP

Tags: django, virtualenv, django-apps

I want to install a django-app without PIP.

I'm using virtualenv with django.

The app is this: https://github.com/garmoncheg/django_multiuploader

that doesn't support PIP.

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pip` is just a generic package installer that defaults to pulling packages from PyPi (the official Python package repository). However, it can install apps from other repositories, source revision control systems (like Git) or even local archives.

If you want to pull the app directly from github, you can just do:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/garmoncheg/django_multiuploader#egg=django-multiuploader
```

See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/vcs-support/

Comment: The package is not optimized for pip then this solution don't work.

Comment: It doesn't have to be "optimized for pip". If it's setup to install at all, pip will install it. If it's not setup to install, then there's no way to install it, period, so if you want to use it, you'll just have to drop it in your project.

Comment: And now that I actually look at the source, that would be the case. There's no way to install this as a package unless you want to fork it and add the setup config yourself. Otherwise, you'll have to just drop it into your project as if it was your own app. You can include it as a git submodule if your project also uses git.

Answer (score 0):

[Download the zip archive](https://github.com/garmoncheg/django_multiuploader/zipball/master), extract the `multiuploader` directory to the same directory where you have `manage.py`, then follow the directions from the github page.